# First order non linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve this differential equation:

$y'(x) = \frac{(3kx^2-1)}{x} y^2 + \frac{y}{x}$

where $k$ is a positive constant.

I know the solution should be

$y(x)=\frac{1}{1-kx^2}$

but I do not know how to get there. I have tried with separation of variables but it's obviously not working. Can someone explain the procedure to get to the solution?

Comment: did you try completing squares? do $y=(my+a/x)^2$ or any like this and try solve

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Introduce the function $z(x)=1/y(x)$, then $z'(x) = -y'(x)/y^{2}(x)$. Rewrite the differential equation:

$$-z'(x) = (3kx^2-1)/x + z(x)/x,$$
multiply by $x$ to obtain
$$(xz(x))'= 1-3kx^2,$$integrate
$$xz(x) = x - kx^3+c$$ or $$z(x) = 1-kx^2+c/x,$$revert to $y$:
$$y(x) = \frac{1}{1-kx^2+c/x}.$$

Comment: Care to explain the downvotes?